# Loading silverlight theme based on setting

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, themes

I am working on a silverlight application that is into an advanced stage of development. I am fairly new to the silverlight. We have a requirement to support multiple themes/styling for the application. From what i have understood based on googling, i will add all the resource files (all supported themes) in ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries.But i am not able to identify at what stage/event (in App.xaml) i can check my site setting and apply the corresponding theme (add the resource dictionary i want to use) in c#.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.